# Why is this variable being assigned on the right side instead of the left when destructuring?

Tags: javascript

I started recently to use object deconstruction and I'm curious about why the variable assignation looks the way it does when using different variable names.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#assigning_to_new_variable_names

```
const o = {p: 42, q: true};
const {p: foo, q: bar} = o;

console.log(foo); // 42
console.log(bar); // true
```

Why is the variable being assigned to the right instead of the left? Is this something only used while destructuring? In my head it should look like this:

```
const {foo: p, bar: q} = o;
```

Comment: It looks like this because this is the way it was defined to work. It mirrors the shorthand object syntax, so perhaps that was a consideration but at the end of the day it's that way because specs say so.

Comment: that's how deconstruction works ... you can do deeper deconstruction .. `const {x:{y:a}}` i.e. equiv: `a = object.x.y` - which would be messier with reversed semantics

Comment: Exactly, for me it looks reversed. I'm the type of guy that expects more than "Because that's how it's done". So there is no justification behind that choice?

Comment: @CharlieAraya so, you expect an answer from the people who ratified it. *They* can give you a rationale. Beware that the rationale might not be satisfying. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293819)

Comment: @CharlieAraya - how would you think `const a = object.x.y` would be written? `const {a: x:{y}} = object`?? then if you wanted `a = object.x.y, b = object.x.z`  ... `const {a: x{y}, b: x{z}} = object` ... or `const {x: {a:y, b:z}} = object`

Comment: In that case I would have expected { a: x.y, b: x.z }. But I guess we would here run into problems if for example property y on object x was undefined, like { a: x.y.z }, but the same happens while deconstructing ({y: {z: a}} = x)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples to show how it works:

```
const obj = {A: [2, 7, 324, 55, -5.6], False: 0, E: Math.E};

const {A: [FirstArrayElement], E, PI = 3} = obj;
console.log(A); //undefined
console.log(FirstArrayElement); //2
console.log(False); //undefined
console.log(E); //2.718281828459045
console.log(PI); //3

const {A: {3: FourthArrayElement}} = obj;
console.log(FourthArrayElement); //55
```

> Why is the variable being assigned to the right instead of the left? Is this something only used while destructuring? In my head it should look like this:
>
> ```
> const {foo: p, bar: q} = o;
> ```

This is just how it was decided in the specs. Unluckly you have to get used to it.

Answer (score -1):

When doing destructuring, you must provide the same structure on the left as on the right, with values replaced with targets (e.g. variables). Basically, you take the right object and replace its values with your targets. So if the right object is

```
{key : someValue}
```

the left object must be

```
{key : I-want-that-value-to-be-stored-here}
```

while the object shortcut notation like `{key}` has the usual meaning `{key: key}`, so the target for the value under `key` will be the variable named `key`.

The same applies to arrays as well:

```
let [targetForTheFirstValue, 
     targetForTheSecondValue] = [firstValue, secondValue]
```

To put it scientifically, destructuring in Javascript is unification, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science) for details.

Comment: How does this answer _"why the variable assignation looks the way it does"_ or _"Why is the variable being assigned to the right instead of the left?"_ or _"Is this something only used while destructing?"_

Comment: My question was regarding variable renaming while deconstructing. So for example you have the object = {key : someValue}. If I deconstruct it and want to rename the key to otherKey I would have to do this while deconstructing {key: otherKey} = obj. And not {otherKey: key} = obj.

Comment: @CharlieAraya: destructuring is not about renaming. It's a unification, that is, an operation of comparing two structures and populating some variables as a side effect. Basically, your variables ("otherKey") are placeholders for values.

Comment: I know it is primarily not about renaming, but it can be done if you want to have a different key name. Check the section "Assigning to new variable names"
here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: yes, in that example `foo` is unified with `42` and `bar` with `true`. It's like regular expressions - think of the left object as a pattern, and variable names as capturing groups.